# Load Next Set Of Images On Listview

Tags: android, listview, caching, android-listview, picasso

I am using `Picasso` for image download and set `Imageview` on `Listview` On Request but now i want to load Next set of Images and Cached it so that user feel convienient to see images when next set of list items and avoid any kind of loader on list item . So please let me know any way to sort out this issue or any solution .

E.g ImageLoading On Listview (Thumb_arr contains Image URI's).

```
Picasso.with(context).load(Thumb_Arr.get(pos).toString()).fit().into(holder.res_img_thumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to preload images before your adapter ?
I think it's possible by calling Picasso as many times as you want.

Just call this method for every images you want to preload :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(Thumb_Arr.get(pos).toString()).fit().into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    });
```

Like that, Picasso should cache the images on memory or disk, so when your adapter call

```
Picasso.with(context).load(Thumb_Arr.get(pos).toString()).fit().into(holder.res_img_thumb);
```

Picasso will get it in his cache.

But you should implements OnScrollListener and link it to your ListView, you will know the current items visible and avoid preloading images on these positions.